# language-tool-python не может подключиться к локальному серверу

Tags: python, сервер

Хотя он у меня загружен и установлен, он выдает эту ошибку

```
>>> import language_tool_python
>>> tool = language_tool_python.LanguageTool('en-US')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rusich/pbcli/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "/home/rusich/pbcli/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 95, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/home/rusich/pbcli/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rusich/pbcli/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/home/rusich/pbcli/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 398, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/home/rusich/pbcli/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 239, in request
    super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1282, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1328, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1277, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1037, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 975, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/home/rusich/pbcli/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 205, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/home/rusich/pbcli/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 186, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f59af2a4fd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rusich/pbcli/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 489, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/home/rusich/pbcli/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/home/rusich/pbcli/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8081): Max retries exceeded with url: /v2/languages (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f59af2a4fd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rusich/pbcli/lib/python3.10/site-packages/language_tool_python/server.py", line 218, in _query_server
    with requests.get(url, params=params, timeout=self._TIMEOUT) as response:
  File "/home/rusich/pbcli/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rusich/pbcli/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rusich/pbcli/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/rusich/pbcli/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rusich/pbcli/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 565, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8081): Max retries exceeded with url: /v2/languages (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f59af2a4fd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/rusich/pbcli/lib/python3.10/site-packages/language_tool_python/server.py", line 71, in __init__
    self._language = LanguageTag(language, self._get_languages())
  File "/home/rusich/pbcli/lib/python3.10/site-packages/language_tool_python/server.py", line 198, in _get_languages
    for e in self._query_server(url, num_tries=1):
  File "/home/rusich/pbcli/lib/python3.10/site-packages/language_tool_python/server.py", line 232, in _query_server
    raise LanguageToolError('{}: {}'.format(self._url, e))
language_tool_python.utils.LanguageToolError: http://127.0.0.1:8081/v2/: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8081): Max retries exceeded with url: /v2/languages (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f59af2a4fd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

Comment: То же самое
Причем на одном компе работает, на другом отказывается
Я загружаю 2 тулы, одну на Рус, другую Англ
Если одну из них убрать,то всё окей Как-то решили эту проблему?

Comment: Проблема не решилась, но теперь я знаю что она не работает под Arch, я просто решил запускать в Docker, там она везде работает замечательно